# group by in SQL, improvement of query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am facing one small issue.
I have a table `MY_CHART_TABLE(ID,REASON_CODE,QUANTITY)`

```
101 CompFail    57
101 FitFinish   18
101 CompDamage  16

102 NoFail      57
102 NoFinish    18

103 FullDamage  16
```

output I want

```
101 CompFail    57   3
101 FitFinish   18   3
101 CompDamage  16   3

102 NoFail      57   2
102 NoFinish    18   2

103 FullDamage  16   1
```

I need to store count at the end based on id. how can I do it?

I am using below query

```sql
SELECT 
   id, 
   reason_code, 
   quantity, 
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id )
FROM MY_CHART_TABLE;
```

Is there any better way to improve the query? can it be done using group by?

Comment: Your query is the right way to do this.

Comment: Your query is fine.

Comment: Can it be done using group by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is fine as is, but if you must use `group by`, you can use a derived table to obtain the counts before you `join` it back to the main table.

```
select a.*, b.counts 
from MY_CHART_TABLE a 
join (select id, count(*) as counts 
      from MY_CHART_TABLE 
      group by id) b on a.id=b.id;
```

For your problem, I would reiterate that your code is the cleaner and better way of doing this. Note that your code as is will count all the rows per id. If you only need to count distinct rows per id, you can add a `group by`. `Window functions` are applied after `group by`, so this way- you'll be counting only distinct rows per id

```
select id, reason_code, quantity, count(*)  over (partition by id)
from MY_CHART_TABLE
group by id, reason_code, quantity;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTEs with group by

```
;with cnts as(
    select 
        id,
        [count] = count(*)
    from MY_CHART_TABLE
    group by id
)
    select mct.*, cnts.[count]
    from MY_CHART_TABLE mct
    join cnts 
        on cnts.id = mct.id
```